# Shopify Storefront API - How Do I Get All Articles on the site?

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-storefront-api

I'm new to Shopify's Storefront API, and I'm trying to get all articles from a specific blog. Every query to the Storefront API that I've ever seen has the 'first: x' argument. My question is - in the code below, on the fifth line, what can I replace 'first: 250' with in order to return all of the articles for this blog, regardless of how many there are?

```
query getBlogByHandle($handle: String!) {
blog(handle: $handle) {
    id
    title
    articles(first: 250) {
        edges {
            node {
                image { url }
                title
                content
                publishedAt
                onlineStoreUrl
                tags
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We have 289 blogs on our site, but somehow if I enter a number higher than 250 for the 'first' argument, I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'articles')
```